# count date difference in hours using php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, date

How can i find the date difference in hours using php and mysql both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`TIMEDIFF()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff) then take the part before the first colon to get the hours.

Answer (score 1):

For MySQL there are a number of [DATE/TIME functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html), DATEDIFF(), SUBDATE(), SUBTIME()