# Check the time difference between two times?

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [count date difference in hours using php and mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2453846/count-date-difference-in-hours-using-php-and-mysql)

I have a MySQL table, in which there's a column `some_column`. This column is set as `datetime`, and when it's updated it's updated as `NOW()`.

What I want to do is query the db, that `some_column`'s value, and check the time difference between whatever is in there and the time it is when querying. I want to see if more than 2 hours has passed.

How do I do that with PHP ? Or do I do that with MySQL ?

Comment: @hakre - It's not in the same context even though it's almost the same thing.

Comment: @hakre - No problem, I just didn't find that question, I found other though, but not as close as this one you posted :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT IF(TIMEDIFF(NOW(),`some_column`) > '02:00:00',1,0) FROM `table`
```

Or, if you're trying to return rows that were updated over two hours ago:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `some_column` < DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL -2 HOUR)
```

Comment: I'm just looking to see if more than two hours passed, and if so I'll update all the columns with new data :)

Comment: Then this is exactly what you're looking for. Field #0 returned from the query will either be 1 if 2 hours or more passed; 0 otherwise. You could assign it a name using "AS" (e.g. "SELECT IF(TIMEDIFF(NOW(),`some_column`) > '02:00:00',1,0) AS morethan FROM `table`"). Then you'll have $row['morethan'] fetched (and $row[0]).

Comment: @qualcuno - So if I'm using it in this manner: `$sql = "SELECT IF(TIMEDIFF(NOW(),last_update) > '02:00:00',1,0) AS morethan FROM products";

  if($stmt = $this->connect->prepare($sql)) {
         $stmt->execute();
   $stmt->bind_result($time);
   $stmt->fetch();
   $stmt->close();
  } else {
   return false;
  }` what do I get ? I guess nothing :) I just want to get that time difference and I can't seem to be able to.

Comment: $stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT IF(TIMEDIFF(NOW(),last_update) > '02:00:00',1,0) FROM products"); $time = (BOOL)$stmt->fetchColumn(0); $stmt->closeCursor();

Answer (score 3):

take a look at `TIMEDIFF` function

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 

$time = // Run query to get datetime value from db

$time = strtotime($time);

$dif = time()-$time;

$dif = date('H', $dif);

if($dif >= 2) 
{
    // Do something
}

?>
```

Comment: OK, this one seems more suitable for me